How to regress multiple gaussian peaks from a spectrogram using scipy?
I have this code that aims to fit the data in here DriveFilelink
The function read_file is utilized to extract information in a structured manner. However, I'm encountering challenges with the Gaussian fit, evident from the discrepancies observed in the Gaussian fit image. This issue appears to stem from the constraints imposed on certain parameters, such as fixing the mean of all the Gaussians and three out of the four amplitudes. Despite these constraints, they are necessary as they are based on available information.
Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? In order to have a better fit.
The code is the following:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from google.colab import drive
import os
# Mount Google Drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')


# Function to read numeric data from a file
def read_numeric_data(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='latin1') as f:
        data = []
        live_time = None
        real_time = None
        for line in f:
            if 'LIVE_TIME' in line:
                live_time = line.strip()
            elif 'REAL_TIME' in line:
                real_time = line.strip()
            elif all(char.isdigit() or char in ".-+e" for char in line.strip()):
                row = [float(x) for x in line.split()]
                data.extend(row)
    return np.array(data), live_time, real_time



file_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/ProjetoXRF_Manuel/April2024/20240402_In.mca'
data, _, _ = read_numeric_data(file_path)

a = -0.0188026396003431
b = 0.039549044037714
Data = data





# Función para convolucionar múltiples gaussianas
def multi_gaussian(x, *params):
    
    eps = 1e-10
    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    amplitude_relations = [1,0.5538, 0.1673 , 0.1673*0.5185 ]
    meanvalues= [24.210, 24.002 , 27.276 , 27.238]
    amplitude = params[0]

    for i in range(4):
        sigma = params[i * 3 + 2]  # Get the fitted standard deviation for this Gaussian
        
        y += amplitude*amplitude_relations[i]* np.exp(-(x - meanvalues[i])**2 / (2 * sigma**2 + eps))
    return y


sigma=[]
area=[]

# Función para graficar el espectro de energía convolucionado
def plot_convolved_spectrum(Data, a, b,i, ax=None):

    maxim = np.max(Data)
    workingarray = np.squeeze(Data)

    # Definir puntos máximos
    peaks, _ = find_peaks(workingarray / maxim, height=0.1)
    peak_values = workingarray[peaks] / maxim
    peak_indices = peaks

    # Calcular valores de energía correspondientes a los picos
    energy_spectrum = a + b * peak_indices

    # Preparar datos para convolución
    data = workingarray[:885] / maxim
    data_y = data / data.max()
    data_x = a + b * np.linspace(0, 885, num=len(data_y))

    # Ajustar múltiples gaussianas al espectro de energía
    peak_indices2, _ = find_peaks(data_y, height=0.1)
    peak_amplitudes = [1,0.5538, 0.1673 , 0.1673*0.5185 ]
    peak_means = [24.210, 24.002 , 27.276 , 27.238]
    peak_sigmas = [0.1] * 4

    params_init = list(zip(peak_amplitudes, peak_means, peak_sigmas))
    params_init = np.concatenate(params_init)

    # Ajustar curva
    params, params_cov = curve_fit(multi_gaussian, data_x, data_y, p0=params_init)

    # Obtener una interpolación de alta resolución del ajuste
    x_fine = np.linspace(data_x.min(), data_x.max(), num=20000)

    y_fit = multi_gaussian(x_fine, *params)

    #  Data Graphic
    ax.scatter(data_x, data_y, color='black', marker='o', s=20, label = 'Data' )
    y_data_error =np.sqrt(workingarray[:885])
    ax.plot(data_x, data_y + y_data_error/maxim, color='black',linestyle='--')
    ax.plot(data_x, data_y - y_data_error/maxim, color='black',linestyle='--')
    # Fit Graphic

    ax.plot(x_fine, y_fit, label="Fit", linewidth=1.5)



    # Extraer desviaciones estándar y amplitudes
    sigmas_array = params[2::3]
    # Calcular sigma promedio
    sigma.append(np.mean(sigmas_array))

    # Configuración del gráfico
    ax.set_xlabel('Energy (KeV)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Normalized Data')
    ax.legend()
    ax.set_title('Convolved Energy Spectrum')

    # Imprimir información
    print("Standard deviations:", sigmas_array)






fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_convolved_spectrum(Data, a, b,1,ax=ax)
ax.set_xlim(22, 28)
plt.show()

Note
I've experimented with setting bounds and refining initial guesses to improve the Gaussian fit. However, it's important to note that working with bounds isn't equivalent to fixing parameters. My aim is to maintain a degree of freedom of just two parameters: the amplitude of the first Gaussian and the standard deviation of all Gaussians. While exploring these adjustments, I'm striving to strike a balance between constraint and flexibility to achieve the desired fit accuracy.
Note
This is the model:

The parameters of the Gaussian function are defined as follows: A represents the amplitude, x_0 denotes the mean value, and sigma represents the standard deviation. In the context of analyzing energy spectra, I possess prior knowledge about the mean values and the relationships governing the amplitudes. Consequently, I aim to constrain certain parameters (such as A and mean) based on this known information. Specifically, I intend to fit only the first amplitude and then utilize the known relationships, such as A2 = 0.1673 * A1 for the second peak. And the to fit the corresponding standar deviation.
Why using a sum  of gaussians?.
The apparent singularity of the first peak in the plot might suggest a single Gaussian. However, this is not the case. The Gaussian representing this energy peak actually consists of two Gaussians that are summed together. This complexity arises because the energy emission at that level comprises two distinct values, 24.002 and 24.210. And due to the resolution of the experiment we are not able to distinguish them just by seen the plot.
And for all these reasons is that I am trying to fix some parameters.
If someone has issue with the data here it is:
extracted data.txt

A sum of Gaussians is known as a "Gaussian Mixture Model".  There is much deep theory here, and you can get MLE from these quickly with expectation-maximization algorithms.  Probably best to not implement yourself, use sklearn

Here is a MCVE showing how to regress a variable number of peaks from the significant part of your signal.
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal, stats, optimize

We load you data and post-process it to get physical series:
data = pd.read_csv("20240402_In.mca", encoding="latin-1", names=["y"]).loc[12:2058]
data["y"] = pd.to_numeric(data["y"])
data["y"] /= data["y"].max()
data["x"] = -0.0188026396003431 + 0.039549044037714 * data.index

data = data.loc[(20. <= data["x"]) & (data["x"] <= 30.), :]

We create the model which accept a variable number of peaks (driven by find_peaks solution):
def peak(x, A, s, x0):
    law = stats.norm(loc=x0, scale=s)
    return A * law.pdf(x) / law.pdf(x0)

def model(x, *parameters):
    n = len(parameters) // 3
    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(n):
        y += peak(x, *parameters[(i * 3):((i + 1) * 3)])
    return y

We identify peaks:
indices, bases = signal.find_peaks(data.y, prominence=0.0125)
#(array([ 67, 118, 195, 210]),
# {'prominences': array([0.01987281, 0.99920509, 0.18918919, 0.03338633]),
#  'left_bases': array([  1,   1, 179, 205]),
#  'right_bases': array([ 76, 160, 219, 219])})

This is the key point, from the identification, we create our educated guess:
x0s = data.x.values[indices]
As = bases["prominences"]
ss = (data.x.values[bases["right_bases"]] - data.x.values[bases["left_bases"]]) / 8.
p0 = list(itertools.chain(*zip(As, ss, x0s)))
#[0.01987281399046105,
# 0.37077228785356864,
# 22.682348638047493,
# 0.9992050874403816,
# 0.7860372502495658,
# 24.699349883970907,
# 0.1891891891891892,
# 0.19774522018856988,
# 27.744626274874886,
# 0.033386327503974564,
# 0.06921082706599968,
# 28.337861935440593]

Now we regress the model wrt your dataset:
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, data.x, data.y, p0=p0)
#array([1.03735804e-02, 9.61270732e-01, 2.29030214e+01, 9.92651381e-01,
#   1.59694755e-01, 2.46561911e+01, 1.85332645e-01, 1.21882422e-01,
#   2.77807838e+01, 3.67805911e-02, 1.21890416e-01, 2.83583849e+01])

We can now estimate the model:
yhat = model(data.x, *popt)

Graphically, it leads to:

Which is quite satisfactory for the unconstrained fit but certainly does not fulfill the constraint you want to enforce.
Could you publish your data ready for coding as arrays in your post?

I acknowledge that your code produces a satisfactory fit and addresses some aspects of the problem. However, it achieves this without employing a Gaussian fit or constraining the variables, which were central to my original concept. The convolution of Gaussian fits is the appropriate model for this dataset, because it is an energy spectrum.  Thank you for your answer. Maybe we can figure out how to solve the problem of using constraints for a gaussian fit.

Welcome to SO. The fitted peaks are certainly Gaussian (see documentation to convince you). Would you mind update your post with the formula of the exact model you expect, mainly what do you mean by convolution in your context (I don't see any convolution operator in code your provided). Then we do not have to dig into the code to try to understand what you are trying to achieve. That would definitely help.

Also could you confirm that the four peaks showed in the answer are the peaks you are interested in. Additionally emphasizes in your question how constraints must be added to your model.

To clarify, the curve fit actually involves a sum of Gaussians rather than a convolved Gaussian fit. Thank you for bringing that up. I would upload the model. To my understanding, the solution you provided doesn't utilize Gaussian functions, correct? Perhaps I'm mistaken, but that's how I interpreted it. And again thanks for answering

No, the model you are seeing does involve sum of Gaussian with a small difference on how A is computed. I just use the convenience of scipy to compute them as I will not do better than the library. What you are asking for constraint is important as it will change the strategy to solve it. As a first glance you can check the regressed parameters and do some arithmetic on it to check out if they are valid parameters within the errors (variance matrix).

I will do that, i added more information to the post, tell me if now it is easier to understand.

So the big prominent peak is as sum of two Gaussian with very close x0. And the two subsequent peaks at the right are dependent of the two first. This is why you have 4 peaks to regress and we can forget about the small one on the left. Am I getting it right?

Yes that is right, and how close are x_0 is the same for the other two peaks. As you can see in the meanvalues. And these are the amplitudes and the mean values      amplitude_relations = [1,0.5538, 0.1673 , 0.16730.5185 ]
meanvalues= [24.210, 24.002 , 27.276 , 27.238]. So the fixed values are going to be all the means, and these relations  [0.5538, 0.1673 , 0.16730.5185 ]. That  are going to be multiplied by the fitted amplitude of the first peak.

Mmmm, it seems data I have does not pass by the x0 you want as constraints. Could you post the exact subset you want to fit, properly scaled as x and y numpy array in your post.

Sorry i did not understand, this part:  it seems data I have does not pass by the x0. You mean that the experimental values does not match with the teorical ones?. Note that for the values 24.002 and 27.238, the data does not provide that info, given that the the resolution of the experiment does not able to distiguish that peaks.

We must be sure we are working on the same dataset. My version of scaled series from your file does not pass by x0. So we are not working on the same data. Could you please post your dataset filtered and scaled as code on your post. See my answer edit.

Im sure that we are working with the same data

Aaaa now i understand. The first part of my code is intended to do that. If you know in which directory you are working, the function read_numeric_data, gives as an output the Data as an array. But i can add the array of 2048 values to the post. I do not know if is going to as  clear as wotking with the function that aims to do that automatically.

I am sure we are not, simply because we are parsing a raw file differently. So please just update your post on the exact dataset you want to fit as arrays in the code.

i just added a txt file with the data extracted. But it is what it is, I am not changing anything of the numeric values when I extract them with the read:numeric function

This is the most effective method I've discovered for parameter fixation in Python thus far. In this instance, I'm employing the same dataset as before. However, I'm only fitting the parameters for the first Gaussian, without considering the fact that it's actually a combination of two Gaussians.
I've divided the fit into two parts: a rough estimate and a refined one. The refined fit constrains the data within ±3 sigma, as it tends to yield better performance.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes


# Define the Gaussian function
def gaussian(x, amplitude, mean, stddev):
    return amplitude * np.exp(-((x - mean) / stddev)**2 / 2)

# Data that is going to be analysed

x_data= a + b * np.linspace(0, 885, 885)
y_data =data[:885]/np.max(data[:885])


#### Bounds for the first gaussian

# Define bounds for the parameters
bounds = ([0, 24.21, 0], [1, 24.22, 2])
y_data_error =np.sqrt(data[:885])/np.max(data[:885])
# Fit the data to the Gaussian function with bounds
params, covariance = curve_fit(gaussian, x_data, y_data, bounds=bounds)

# Create the model
gaussian_model = Model(gaussian)

# Create parameters with initial values
A_value = 1.0  # Initial value for amplitude
mu_value = 24.21  # Initial value for mean
sigma_value = 1.0  # Initial value for standard deviation
params = gaussian_model.make_params(amplitude=A_value, mean=mu_value, stddev=sigma_value)

# Fix amplitude and mean
#params['amplitude'].vary = False
params['mean'].vary = False

# Fit the model to the data
result = gaussian_model.fit(y_data, params, x=x_data)

# Extract the parameters
amplitude = result.params['amplitude'].value
mean = result.params['mean'].value
stddev = result.params['stddev'].value

# Data interpolation
x_fine = np.linspace(x_data.min(), x_data.max(), num=1000)
y_fit= result.eval(x=x_fine)

ylower_limit = ( (24.21  - 3 * stddev)-a )/b
yupper_limit = ( (24.21  + 3 * stddev)-a )/b

# Selecciona los valores dentro del intervalo

y_limitado = y_data[int(ylower_limit):int(yupper_limit)]

x_limitado = a + b*np.linspace(int(ylower_limit), int(yupper_limit), 24)

ylimit_error=np.sqrt(data[int(ylower_limit):int(yupper_limit)])/np.max(data[int(ylower_limit):int(yupper_limit)])


params1, covariance1 = curve_fit(gaussian, x_limitado, y_limitado, bounds=bounds)

# Create the model
gaussian_model = Model(gaussian)

# Create parameters with initial values
A_value1 = 1.0  # Initial value for amplitude
mu_value1 = 24.21  # Initial value for mean
sigma_value1 = 1.0  # Initial value for standard deviation
params1 = gaussian_model.make_params(amplitude=A_value1, mean=mu_value1, stddev=sigma_value1,sigma=ylimit_error)

# Fix amplitude and mean
#params['amplitude'].vary = False
params1['mean'].vary = False

# Fit the model to the data
result1 = gaussian_model.fit(y_limitado, params1, x=x_limitado)

# Extract the parameters
amplitude1 = result1.params['amplitude'].value
mean1 = result1.params['mean'].value
stddev1 = result1.params['stddev'].value


# Data interpolation
x_fine1 = np.linspace(x_limitado.min(), x_limitado.max(), num=1000)
y_fit1 = result1.eval(x=x_fine1)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.scatter(x_limitado,y_limitado, color='black', marker='o')
ax.plot(x_fine1,y_fit1,color='blue')
ax.plot(x_fine,y_fit,color='green')

ax.errorbar(x_limitado,y_limitado,yerr=ylimit_error, fmt='o', color='red', label='errorbar')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_title('Gaussian Fit to Data')
ax.set_xlim((24.21  - 3 * stddev, 24.21  + 3 * stddev))
ax.legend()
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()


print("Amplitude:", amplitude)
print("Mean:", mean)
print("Standard Deviation:", stddev)
print("Amplitude:", amplitude1)
print("Mean:", mean1)
print("Standard Deviation:", stddev1)

Edit
Now, I have the capability to fix more parameters, allowing me to precisely adjust the fitting of the sum of the first two Gaussians. However, I'm puzzled by the presence of an additional peak in the fit. I'm unsure of its origin.

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Define Gaussian function
def gaussian(x, amplitude, mean, stddev):
    return amplitude * np.exp(-((x - mean) / stddev)**2 / 2)

# Generate x values for the data
x_data = a + b * np.linspace(0, 885, 885)

# Normalize y data
y_data = data[:885] / np.max(data[:885])
y_data_error = np.sqrt(data[:885]) / np.max(data[:885])

# Fit first Gaussian
bounds = ([1 - 0.0001, 24.21, 0], [1, 24.22, 2])  # Define bounds for the parameters
params, covariance = curve_fit(gaussian, x_data, y_data, bounds=bounds)  # Fit Gaussian to data

# Create the model
gaussian_model = Model(gaussian)

# Initial values for parameters
A_value = 1.0
mu_value = 24.21
sigma_value = 1.0
params = gaussian_model.make_params(amplitude=A_value, mean=mu_value, stddev=sigma_value)
params['mean'].vary = False  # Fix mean parameter

# Fit the model to the data
result = gaussian_model.fit(y_data, params, x=x_data)

# Extract parameters
amplitude = result.params['amplitude'].value
mean = result.params['mean'].value
stddev = result.params['stddev'].value

# Data interpolation
x_fine = np.linspace(x_data.min(), x_data.max(), num=1000)
y_fit = result.eval(x=x_fine)

# Determine y limits for data subset
ylower_limit = ((24.21 - 3 * stddev) - a) / b
yupper_limit = ((24.21 + 3 * stddev) - a) / b

# Select subset of data within the limits
y_limitado = y_data[int(ylower_limit):int(yupper_limit)]
x_limitado = a + b * np.linspace(int(ylower_limit), int(yupper_limit), 24)
ylimit_error = np.sqrt(data[int(ylower_limit):int(yupper_limit)]) / np.max(data[int(ylower_limit):int(yupper_limit)])

# Constrained fit
bounds_sum = ([0, 24.21, 0, 0, 24.0, 0], [1, 24.22, 1, 1, 24.1, 1])  # Bounds for parameters

# Define function for sum of Gaussians
def sum_of_gaussians(x, amplitude1, mean1, stddev1, amplitude2, mean2, stddev2):
    gaussian1 = amplitude1 * np.exp(-((x - mean1) / stddev1)**2 / 2)
    gaussian2 = amplitude2 * np.exp(-((x - mean2) / stddev2)**2 / 2)
    return gaussian1 + gaussian2

# Fit the sum of Gaussians to the subset of data
params1, covariance1 = curve_fit(sum_of_gaussians, x_limitado, y_limitado, bounds=bounds_sum, sigma=ylimit_error)

# Create the model
multigaussian_model = Model(sum_of_gaussians)

# Initial values for parameters
A_value1 = amplitude
mu_value1 = 24.22
sigma_value1 = 0.1

A_value2 = amplitude * 0.5388
mu_value2 = 24.002
sigma_value2 = 0.1

# Set parameters for the model
params1 = multigaussian_model.make_params(amplitude1=A_value1, mean1=mu_value1, stddev1=sigma_value1,
                                          amplitude2=A_value2, mean2=mu_value2, stddev2=sigma_value2, sigma=ylimit_error)

# Fix certain parameters
params1['amplitude1'].vary = False
params1['mean1'].vary = False
params1['amplitude2'].vary = False
params1['mean2'].vary = False

# Fit the model to the data
result1 = multigaussian_model.fit(y_limitado, params1, x=x_limitado)

# Extract parameters
amplitude1 = result1.params['amplitude1'].value
mean1 = result1.params['mean1'].value
stddev1 = result1.params['stddev1'].value

amplitude2 = result1.params['amplitude2'].value
mean2 = result1.params['mean2'].value
stddev2 = result1.params['stddev2'].value

# Data interpolation
x_fine1 = np.linspace(x_limitado.min(), x_limitado.max(), num=1000)
y_fit1 = result1.eval(x=x_fine1)

# Individual Gaussians
x = np.linspace(min(mean1 - 3 * stddev1, mean2 - 3 * stddev2),
                max(mean1 + 3 * stddev1, mean2 + 3 * stddev2), 1000)
y1 = gaussian(x, amplitude1, mean1, stddev1)
y2 = gaussian(x, amplitude2, mean2, stddev2)

# Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.scatter(x_limitado, y_limitado, color='black', marker='o')
ax.plot(x_fine1, y_fit1, color='blue')
ax.errorbar(x_limitado, y_limitado, yerr=ylimit_error, fmt='o', color='red', label='errorbar')
ax.plot(x, y1, label='Gaussian 1')
ax.plot(x, y2, label='Gaussian 2')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_title('Gaussian Fit to Data')
ax.set_xlim((24.21 - 3 * stddev, 24.21 + 3 * stddev))
ax.legend()
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()

# Print parameters
print("Amplitude1:", amplitude1)
print("Mean1:", mean1)
print("Standard Deviation1:", stddev1)
print("")
print("Amplitude2:", amplitude2)
print("Mean2:", mean2)
print("Standard Deviation2:", stddev2)

